# Clean Code adding Images

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give styles to the transport links Li, i have done it, but i have the feeling it could be a cleaner code and i am not completely sure if using absolute position is the best approach here, perhaps i should use before pseudoclass.
Could you please point me out what it the best and clean way to achieve this.
Here is the link
Many Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Peo90.png)
[https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14407746/move_bubble_master/index.html][2]

```
              #main .descript strong {
          font-family: 'proxima_nova_altbold';
          display: block;
          font-weight: 700;
          padding: 20px 0px 16px 0px;
          color: #000;
          font-size: 14px;
          border-bottom: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
          }
          /* line 226, ../sass/main.scss */
          #main .descript ol {
          list-style: none;
          padding: 0px;
          width: 100%;
          margin-bottom: 2px;
          }
          /* line 229, ../sass/main.scss */
          #main .descript ol li {
          width: 50%;
          float: left;
          height: 53px;
          border-bottom: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
          position: relative;
          color: #000;
          padding-left: 34px;
          font-size: 13px;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          }
          /* line 236, ../sass/main.scss */
          #main .descript ol li img {
          float: left;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0px;
          top: 0px;
          }
          /* line 237, ../sass/main.scss */
          #main .descript ol li span {
          display: block;
          color: #9c9c9c;
          padding-bottom: 6px;
          }
          /* line 242, ../sass/main.scss */
          #main .descript ol li em {
          font-family: 'proxima_nova_altbold';
          position: absolute;
          top: 0px;
          right: 40px;
          line-height: 76px;
          color: #9c9c9c;
          font-style: normal;
          }
          /* line 250, ../sass/main.scss */
          #main .descript ol li.room {
          line-height: 53px;
          }
          /* line 252, ../sass/main.scss */
          #main .descript ol li.room img {
          width: 23px;
          height: auto;
          left: 3px;
          top: 15px;
          }
          /* line 254, ../sass/main.scss */
          #main .descript ol li.kitchen {
          line-height: 53px;
          }
          /* line 256, ../sass/main.scss */
          #main .descript ol li.kitchen img {
          width: 23px;
          height: auto;
          left: 3px;
          top: 15px;
          }
          /* line 258, ../sass/main.scss */
          #main .descript ol li.kilburn, #main .descript ol li.kilburnPark, #main .descript ol li.maida, #main .descript ol li.south {
          padding: 16px 0px 0px 34px;
          height: 64px;
          }
          /* line 260, ../sass/main.scss */
          #main .descript ol li.kilburn img, #main .descript ol li.kilburnPark img, #main .descript ol li.maida img, #main .descript ol li.south img {
          width: 19px;
          height: auto;
          left: 3px;
          top: 20px;
          }
          /* line 263, ../sass/main.scss */
          #main .descript ol:after {
          clear: both;
          content: "";
          display: table;
          }
```

Comment: Code that is relevant to the question must be pasted into the question itself and not only available via an external link.  Also, you have to fully describe what you're trying to accomplish.  A phrase like `give styles to the transport links` means nothing to people who don't know your project.  Please read [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do not use `<img width="10" height="10" >`. define and use css classes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review, so would be more suitable for the [Code Review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ Alex Kudryashev Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For a start, I recommend you add some classes to some of the more deeply nested elements, and target those classes with your CSS instead of those big multi-tiered selectors you've got at the moment.

This would apply particularly to the bits of code that you've got duplicated; this duplication could be removed if you had the same class defined on all the target elements, rather than having to build a complex selector to each of them individually.

Comment: many thanks, i will change that and i will try not to repeat the code , thank you